# How to center a drop down under its link

Tags: css

I'm trying to center the drop down in the code below, under its link. How is this done? I'll be doing the show/hide part using `jquery`, but I cannot get it to center under the letter `r` which will be a `glyphicon` later.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> New Document </title>
<style type="text/css">
.main{
    width:300px;
    background:cyan;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul {
    list-style:none outside none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
    Left
    <div class="right">
                <span>R</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
                <li>Option 4</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `R` inside the `ul` as the first list element. Add some CSS modifications and you're done.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wq2Ls/1/

You also don't need `.menu` container. All its CSS can be put in the `ul`.
I also replaced the `.right` *span* with a *div*. Span is an inline element and it is not the best practice to put an `ul` inside it.

**EDIT**:
If you set `position:absolute` to the `ul` it is not a block element and won't let the `R` position itself in the center even if the `R` has `text-align:center`. Also the `R` should be put in a `div` that it could fill the whole width of its parent.
Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wq2Ls/5/

Comment: My reason for putting those links in a different span were so I could hide them using `display:none;`. Now how do I hide them?

Comment: you can combine with `:first-child` selector. E.g. `ul > li:first-child` refers to the first `li` element in the `ul`.

Comment: So I put the `r` in a `span`. See my edit. Still cant get the right center under the `r` See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wq2Ls/3/

Comment: :-) The R need to be on the side only. Not centered.

Comment: Fiddle from the last line update. Check it out. Anyway, you could easily do it yourself by removing one line in CSS.